# How to read an array which is received as Ajax response text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The response text I am getting after ajax call.

```
$ Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trade_type] => Carpentry
            [active_status] => 0
            [work_order_received] => 8912629
            [fault_type] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [trade_type] => Carpentry
            [active_status] => 1
            [work_order_received] => 8912629
            [fault_type] => 
        )

)
```

As this has multiple entries how to loop through this and get data.
for example : **var trade_type = carpentry;**

I tried using JSON.pase. but this started to return single character at a time

My Php code which is returning Ajax data.

```
public function get_job_details_by_workorder(){

$workorder = $this->input->post('work_order');
$query=$this->db->query("select trade_type,active_status,work_order_received,fault_type from nrm_doc_header where work_order_received='$workorder'")->result_array();

print_r($query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `json_encode()` it in php first so it gets sent as as `[{"trade_type":"Carpentry"...}]`

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [trade_type] => Carpentry
            [active_status] => 0
            [work_order_received] => 8912629
            [fault_type] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [trade_type] => Carpentry
            [active_status] => 1
            [work_order_received] => 8912629
            [fault_type] => 
        )

) 
 I am receiving from Json encode only

Comment: What am I supposed to see in that comment that is different?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Need to show your basic php and how you get that

Comment: I have added my Php code. Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow so the way I have asked the question might be not right.

Comment: So change `print_r` to `echo json_encode($query);` No worries about being new. Takes a bit of getting used to how it all works

Answer (score 0):

I was missing dataType:Json in my ajax call. so i was getting return in text format.so was not able to parse it.